# Error: OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.MPEG4E does not support color format [android]

Tags: android, encoder

I'm trying to applying an encoder by using MediaCodec. The MediaFormat I use is as follows.

```
 MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/mp4v-es", 640, 480);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 125000);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV422PackedSemiPlanar);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
```

The demo runs well on virtual machine. However, it fails when I test it on the real machine(Samsung Galaxy Tab GT3113). The demo reports errors at the line `codec.configure(mediaFormat, null /* surface */, null /* crypto */, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE /* flags */); codec.start();`
The logcat says:

> 06-24 15:16:54.582: E/ACodec(3146): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.MPEG4E] does
>   not support color format 19 06-24 15:16:54.582: E/ACodec(3146):
>   [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.MPEG4E] configureCodec returning error
>   -2147483648
>
> 06-24 15:16:54.582: E/MediaCodec(3146): Codec reported an error. (omx
>   error 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)

I have tried all the **KEY_COLOR_FORMAT** which are provied by Android, but none of them works.
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: If you use "video/avc", it's highly likely that one of FormatYUV420Planar, FormatYUV420PackedPlanar, FormatYUV420SemiPlanar, FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar, and/or TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar will work.  For an OMX.TI.DUCATI1 codec, it'll be the latter.  The formats are under-specified, but it may end up being the same memory layout as what you expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you're trying to use wrong encoder. Before starting encoder you should "probe" existing encoders using some kind of that:

```
HashMap<String, CodecCapabilities> mEncoderInfos;
void initEncoderInfos(){
    for(int i = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
        if(codecInfo.isEncoder()){
            for(String t : codecInfo.getSupportedTypes()){
                try{
                    mEncoderInfos.put(t, codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType(t));
                } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All info will be collected in mEncoderInfos. And after this you can use most suitable encoder.

In other words: you should not assume that some encoder("video/mp4v-es" in your case) does support some color format(MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV422PackedSemiPlanar in your case).

Comment: Note `CodecCapabilities.colorFormats[]` holds the list of color formats supported by the codec in question.